# Shiny code works when I clear the environment but otherwise throws object 'Year' not found error

Tags: r, shiny

```
options(scipen = 999)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage( 

      tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Home",
       titlePanel("2 Degree Portfolio Alignment Dashboard"),  

       sidebarLayout(
         sidebarPanel(
           downloadButton('downloadData', "Download excel template"),
           div(style = "margin-top:30px"),

           fileInput('file1', 'Upload Portfolio Data',
                     accept = c(".xlsx")),
           downloadButton('downloadData1', "Download analysis results"),
           #downloadButton('file2', "Download Result Excel")
         ),
         mainPanel(
           tableOutput('contents'))
       )

      ),  
      tabPanel("Graph", 
       titlePanel("2 Degree Alignment"), 

       plotOutput(outputId = "main_plot", height = "400px") ),

      tabPanel("Table", 
       titlePanel("Portfolio Results"),


      DT::dataTableOutput("table")
   )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  mydata2<- read.csv(file='TestData3.csv')
  mdf <- melt(mydata2, id.vars="Emissions", value.name="value", variable.name="Year")

  output$main_plot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(data=mdf,aes(x=Year, y= value, group = Emissions, colour= Emissions))+ 
        geom_line(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +  geom_point( size=4, shape=21, fill="white")
        +theme(legend.position="bottom",plot.title = element_text(size=15, face="bold"))    })
```

Comment:

The above code works at first but after running other apps it stops working and throws object 'Year' not found error can someone shed light on how should I declare 'Year' in melt or how to avoid that error.

Comment: In short: is this statement wrong to declare 'Year'?                                                                                          
mdf <- melt(mydata2, id.vars="Emissions", value.name="value", variable.name="Year")

Comment: You can try use varnames instead of variable.name

Comment: and you're not loading the reshape2 library so you might have to use. ```reshape2::melt(...```

Comment: Thanks! actually I missed to add that here but that is in my original code. Also, varnames gives object not found error everytime even when I clear the environment while variable. name works after clearing.